# Prompt alert used in settings application

Tags: ios

I notice this prompt style, and i liked it more than the UIAlertView prompt, so i am wondering, is it a customized UIAlertView or just a UIView containing two buttons which gets animated up and down programatically like any other UIView. Thanx.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a `UIActionSheet`, not `UIAlertView`, and has been around since iOS 2.0. [Here is the documentation for it](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).